# Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Estoy lanzando un `jobs` de Jenkins que a su vez lanza una llamada groovy.
Esta llamada groovy funciona perfectamente, pero no desde Jenkins.

El script es:

```
import groovy.util.XmlParser
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

String xml_steps = new File("/tmp/steps_Devops.xml").text
def GPathResult steps_Devops = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml_steps)
def GPathResult sUUAA = steps_Devops.children().find { GPathResult node ->
node.name() == 'UUAA' && node.getProperty("@name") == 'EZGN'
}


def GPathResult create_release_structure = sUUAA.children().find { 
GPathResult node ->node.name() == 'Create_release_structure'
}
create_release_structure.text()
```

El contenido del fichero es

```
<Steps_Devops>
    <UUAA name="EZGN" proyect="Nombre Proyecto1">
        <Donwload_Sources>Structure</Donwload_Sources>                       
        <Create_release_structure>Structure</Create_release_structure>                       
        <Deploy_release_artifactory>artifactory</Deploy_release_artifactory>
   </UUAA>
</Steps_Devops>
```

Este devuelve el valor "Structure" que es correcto.

Sin embargo desde Jenkins me aparece lo siguiente:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
    at Unknown.Unknown(Unknown)
```

Datos vistos en Jenkins:

```
Pipeline: Groovy    org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:2.49   MIT License
Groovy CPS Execution    com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.24   The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
Pure Java implementation of diff/patch  com.cloudbees:diff4j:1.2    CDDL/GPLv2 dual license
```

¿Donde puede estar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Usa paréntesis para agrupar la condicion, donde pone:

```
node.name() == 'UUAA' && node.getProperty("@name") == 'EZGN'
```

Ponlo :

```
((node.name() == 'UUAA') && (node.getProperty("@name") == 'EZGN'))
```

Creo que esta resolviendo la condicion en el orden que no esperas.